# Are 'transfarring' or cross-game saves region free?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, metal-gear-solid-series

Several games available on both the Vita and PS3 allow you to sync your progress between platforms, for example, the MGS HD collection for PS3 lets you 'transfar' your MGS2 & 3 saves to the Vita version and back while Peace Walker HD 'transfars' with the PSP version. PS3 games like MLB 12 The Show and the future Sly 4 and PS Heroes All Star Battle Royal will support progress sharing as well.

Since PSP, PS3 and Vita are region free, you may have any of these games from different regions. Do I need to have all versions of the same region? Or will transfarring work even if I have games from different region?

Note: <s>Right now since MGS HD collection is the only available game to support this which came out on different regions (MLB 12 was North America only), so I assume answers will be valid to the MGS collection only.</s> The current games which support this now are MGS HD Collection, MotorStorm RC, MLB 12 The Show (Only the Vita version came out in Europe) & PSASBR. Future games should include R&C:Q-Force/FFA, Sly 4 and ZOE HD.

Comment: The answer is probably going to depend on the game.

Comment: I might change my question to be about MGS only

Comment: Can I throw out that I think "transfar" is a ridiculous term, apropos of nothing else related to the question?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh: The word "transfarring" is just a transliteration of 'transferring' from English to Japanese (eg. トランスファーリング - toransufaaringu) and back to English using the Japanese pronunciation. It's also been way overblown by the US gaming media.

Comment: I rolled back the edit on this question, 'transfarring' is the correct name for the Kojima production games, see [here](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Transfarring)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is based on language.

If you have a game localized in a specific language which your game does not support for your region and you try to import that saved game, it will not work; however, if the save game is localized with multiple languages, one of which is yours, then it should work. Operative there is, 'should', and I say this because no game is developed the same way and there is no ISO on how a save game should be developed.

Answer (score 2):

Games from different regions have different game codes. This means the save data on your console is theoretically identified differently based on these game IDs. So, based on this, it means that cross-saved files won't work if the games are from different regions. The console itself would identify the games as being different, so it wouldn't pick up the save data.

This also applies to digital vs retail games. These have different codes, so save data cannot be used cross versions. I know this to be fact as my retail copy of Burnout Paradise save data isn't compatible with the Digital version of the game game I got free with PlayStation Plus.

Comment: All you said is true, but I'm not so sure it applies to cross platform games. The cross saves aren't just copied between devices, they go some sort of conversion, I'm assuming the cross-save/transfarring process checks each game's progress and the creates a updates the other device's save. Therefore I'm not sure if this process is locked between regions of games.

Comment: As for your comment about save data incompatible between digital and retail versions, that's also not given. My inFAMOUS retail save worked fine with the digital copy (from the Welcome Back offer); My R&C:A4O retail save didn't work with the digital version.

Comment: Then that really means the developer is in control of how the save data works between different versions.

As for cross-save, I believe you may be correct. The game itself would download the save data from the cloud and convert it to a format usable on that device. This means (again depending on the developer) that cross-save data should work across different regions. In the end, it's linked to your PSN account, so it should be ok.

Comment: I'm hoping someone who has different-region copies of games can test this, for example, US PS3 MGS HD vs EU Vita MGS HD

Answer (score 0):

I know that the Japanese and US releases of the HD collection are different, specifically to their transfarring compatibility. I'd say the safe bet is keep in the same region to use transfarring, but if you have a manual save you want to load, you should be able to do that, THEN transfar it.